# Ubuntu Gnome 3.0 Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R Screencast Recorder not working

Tags: gnome, screencast

I'm trying to record a video, but nothing is happening when I'm pressing Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R, while the [wiki claims](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeShell/CheatSheet#Screencast_recording) that I'm supposed at least to see a red circle at the bottom.

Are there some prerequisites? I've just installed the Gnome and haven't tweaked any settings. Here's some system info:

```
lsb_release -a
Release:    12.10
```

and,

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.6.3.1
```

Comment: I am able to do that in my 12.04

Comment: what is your gnome-shell --version ?

Comment: GNOME Shell 3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the gnome shell to v 3.8 and the recording is working as expected now.